# why role of my user is null (membership)?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-membership

I implemented the membership in  asp.net 4.0, I have 3 roles(manager,operator,user) and 2 user (manager,operator). manager can define the user, I do that by this code:

```
Membership.CreateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtEmail.Text);
```

and I set its role by below code:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(txtUserName.Text, "user");
```

now when the user want to log in, I check the user by:

```
if(Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text)){
string[] role = Roles.GetRolesForUser(txtUserName.Text);
.
.
.
}
```

and I check the role array, but it is null, and I can not get the role of user, of course when I log in by manager or operator there is no problem,
now my question is that why my user role is null?
thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the roles provider to the web.config?

Answer (score 0):

```
if user is logged , you can use directly 

rolesArray = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
```